# Office 365 login with only onmicrosoft domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, microsoft-office-365

I'm at a company right now, where I was given two email addresses.

someDude@mycompany.com
someDude@n45564jck.onmicrosoft.com

I can receive email at someDude@mycompany.com using the outlook client, but I can't login to Office 365 with that.  I can only login to Office 365 using someDude@n45564jck.onmicrosoft.com.  Any idea what is going on here?  I thought when you added the MX record to the 365 Admin > Domains > mycompany.com it would allow login using the mycompany.com?

Comment: @yoonix, can someone help me understand why this is off topic?  It's about administrating a Office 365 tenet.

Answer (score 2):

> I can only login to Office 365 using
> someDude@n45564jck.onmicrosoft.com

Correct. That's your Office 365 User Principal Name. It's not directly related to your email address and has nothing to do with MX records.

It's not ideal, but there's nothing technically wrong with it. Ideally, your Office 365 User Principal Name and your Primary SMTP address would match, but someone borked your company's Office 365 implementation and migration. It's probably fixable, but without having access to your Office 365 tenant and optionally your on premises directory, there's no way to tell what exactly would need to be done. There are a number of reasons why your Office 365 tenant is configured the way it is.